# About BSplines and Beziers

Tags: genetic-algorithm, bezier, splines

I'm doing a small drawing-test program and I'm drawing curves.

While it has been pretty easy with Beziers, I'm stuck with Splines. Like with first, when I click in the window, I add a knot, but honestly I don't get how to draw my curve from here: how do I compute values like I do with Beziers (see below)?

```
///> Coefficient calc in algorithm
///> dT Sampled in [0,1]
///> bla bla bla
vdCoeff[0] = ( 1 - dT ) * ( 1 - dT ) * ( 1 - dT );
vdCoeff[1] = dT *( 1 - dT ) * ( 1 - dT );
vdCoeff[2] = dT * dT * ( 1 - dT );
vdCoeff[3] = dT * dT * dT;
///> bla bla bla
```

Comment: You've left some assumptions in your question: we have no idea which language you're using, or which flavour of spline you're talking about. Also usually a good idea not to leave code that does not contribute to your problem in what you're showing, like the "blah" lines. No reasons to include those.

Comment: I'm using C++, but I don't care, you can answer me in Java or "pseudocode". I'm looking for BSplines.

Comment: in that case, [you forgot to search](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379422/b-spline-curves's got you covered, as do several other answers for other languages. (and if you did search SO first, and found several potential questions, but none of them addressed your problem, please explain that in your question)

Comment: Google "Cox DeBoor algorithm" for B-spline curve evaluation.

Comment: I have implemented my own B-Spline/NURBS library: [TinySpline](https://github.com/retuxx/tinyspline). It provides spline evaluation using DeBoor's algorithm. If you want to implement it on you own, have a look at the function `ts_bspline_evaluate`. Maybe it helps you to understand what you need to do. Furthermore, you will find a very good explanation of DeBoor's algorithm at: http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/de-Boor.html